# perl: Config::Simple config file section reading

Tags: perl

I am trying to do the configuration file using `Config::Simple`

The configuration file i.e. new1.conf

```
[Section1]
param1=value1
param2=value2

[Section2]
param1=value1
param2=value2

[Section3]
param1=value1
param2=value2
```

here is my code

```html
use Config::Simple;

$cfg = new Config::Simple(syntax => 'ini');

#
# Get Section Names
# 
$cfg = Config::Simple->import_from('new.conf', \%Config)  or die Config::Simple->error();
my @arr = ( keys %Config );
@arr1 = grep s/\..*//, @arr;
my %uniq;
@uniq{@arr} = ();
@sections = keys %uniq;

foreach my $secname (sort @sections) 
{
    print "section : $secname\n";
    foreach (sort keys %Config) 
    {

        print "$_ : $Config{$_}\n";

    }
}
```

For this i am getting the output like this

```
section : Section1
Section1.param1 : value1
Section1.param2 : value2
Section2.param1 : value1
Section2.param2 : value2
Section3.param1 : value1
Section3.param2 : value2
section : Section2
Section1.param1 : value1
Section1.param2 : value2
Section2.param1 : value1
Section2.param2 : value2
Section3.param1 : value1
Section3.param2 : value2
section : Section3
Section1.param1 : value1
Section1.param2 : value2
Section2.param1 : value1
Section2.param2 : value2
Section3.param1 : value1
Section3.param2 : value2
```

I am trying to compare the section names with paramaters in that respective section.

for that i am trying to write this code

```
foreach my $secname (sort @sections) 
{
    print "section : $secname\n";
    foreach (sort keys %Config) 
    {
        $var = grep { !/\b[A-Za-z0-9.].*[.]/ } @arr;
        if($secname == $var)
        {
            print "$secname\n";
        }
        else
        {
            print "false\n";
        }

        #compare 'secname' vs 'dialer onboard'.xxx
        #print "$_ : $Config{$_}\n";

    }
}
```

This is not working for me. I stuck up here only.For this i am getting output like this

```
section : Section1
false
false
false
false
false
false
section : Section2
false
false
false
false
false
false
section : Section3
false
false
false
false
false
false
```

I cant be able to compare and display the section name with the respective params and values.

And finally i want output like this below.

```
section : Section1
Section1.param1 : value1
Section1.param2 : value2
section : Section2
Section2.param1 : value1
Section2.param2 : value2
section : Section3
Section3.param1 : value1
Section3.param2 : value2
```

or at least i want to display the params.
I think i am doing something wrong in comparing params and section. I am not able to identify that.

Please somebody suggest me where i am going wrong
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should `use strict` and `use warnings`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be making this far more complicated than it needs to be.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Config::Simple;

my $cfg = Config::Simple->import_from('new1.conf', \my %config)
  or die Config::Simple->error();

my $curr_section = '';
foreach (sort keys %config) {
  my ($section, $param) = split /\./;

  if ($section ne $curr_section) {
    say "section : $section";
    $curr_section = $section;
  }
  say "$_: $config{$_}";
}
```

It's even easier if you use a module that is better suited to dealing with INI files.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Config::INI::Reader;

my $cfg = Config::INI::Reader->read_file('new1.conf');

foreach my $section (sort keys %$cfg) {
  say "section: $section";
  foreach my $param (sort keys %{$cfg->{$section}}) {
    say "$section.$param : $cfg->{$section}{$param}"
  }
}
```

Oh, and your problem was caused by using the wrong kind of comparison operator. You want `$secname eq $var`, not `$secname == $var`. Adding `use strict` and `use warnings` to your code is **always** a good idea.